# How to disable focus grabbing for GTK+ tool button

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtkmm, vala

GTK+ Button widget has focus_on_click property that controls grabbing of focus. But I use MenuToolButton that has no such a property. I don't want the focus on click.

How to get rid of it? Thanks!

Comment: did you want a toggle button? (a checkbox?)

Comment: Look at GtkWidget focus related properties, if no one of those works for you, subclass GtkMenuToolButton and handling the click event on your method before pass it over the parent implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want focus_on_click, you probably don't want focus gererally.

```
widget.set_can_focus(False)
```

Comment: Did not help, it grabs it. Very strange!

Comment: It grabs it after start (because its the first button in the window) and then if I click on something else it wont grab it. Partially working...

Comment: Set initial focus to some other widget then.

Comment: `widget.set_can_default(False)` may help.

Comment: used this to remove the, what I think is focus, from a button (which graphically speaking, is a dashed rectangular inside the button, near its border), which insisted on show from the beginning of the application, in the very first widget.